# User deleted and re-added to AD - Profile now empty on MOSS

Tags: 2007, user-profile, ad

A user was accidentally deleted from AD and re-added once we realised what happened, now the user is unable to access the SharePoint site they work within. I re-added the permissions to the specific site with contribute access but this didn't work. When I checked the user's information out within People and Groups I noticed all of their AD attributes are not being picked up.

The Profile Sync and Quick Sync jobs are running every hour and minute and look OK, my question is where should I be looking next to resolve this problem? I have inherited this MOSS environment and have little experience within it so would appreciate any pointers on where to look next. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you deteleted and recreated the User ID(with same user name), in that case you have to run the migrate user command as Pirate mentioned but little differently. You need a temp account on which you migrate the profile first then to the id.

**First migrate to temp id**

```
stsadm -o migrateuser -oldlogin <domain\name> -newlogin <domain\TempID -ignoresidhistory
```

**Then Migrate from Temp to ID**

```
stsadm -o migrateuser -oldlogin <domain\TempID> -newlogin <domain\name> -ignoresidhistory
```

You canot migrate it directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I still get the error 'Error migrating user profile' when running the command however by chance I checked the user info again within People and Groups and noticed the 'Account' attribute had changed to the temp account, then I ran the second command to migrate back to the original account login and again, the same error from the command line but the account attribute had changed.